# How to get a flag counter for anonymous users?

Tags: 7, views, flags

I'd like to have a counter for flagged nodes for anonymous users. I'd like to use a view. In this view I need a relationship to the anonymous user (session).

How can I get it?

Or is there another solution to get a flag counter for anonymous users?

Comment: write a function to get the count for the flag for $user->uid <= 0.

Comment: I don't speak PHP :(

Answer (score 1):

The [Session API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_api) module is required (a prereq) to make the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module functionality available for anonymous users (even with page caching enabled),

Consider checking out the great article about [Enhancing the Anonymous User Experience: Adventures with Flags](https://www.prometsource.com/blog/enhancing-anonymous-user-experience-adventures-flags) to get this to work.